Normals on split curve
Need help after I split curve it's normals changes. I'd like to have normals outside of this curve.
Thanks in advance.



Use "Capture attribute" node.

I've tried to compare captured normal with new one and then flip faces when equal but with not luck

I'm trying to recreate your setup and whenever I convert the mesh to a curve and back into a mesh it seems like it auto calculates the edge normals and makes them consistent? Is that not happening for you?

I 've separated parts of spline by crease and my normals are filped.

You're starting with a face so you can just mark the edges for separation, extrude, and then separate faces extruded from selected edges:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
